# How to persist initial data with JpaRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In order to initially fill the database with data, I created entity instances and wrote a service class that should save them in the database.

In a very simplified way, my model consists of three classes A, B and C. The instances of the classes A and B both reference (the same) instances of C (annotated with `@ManyToOne`):

```
a1 -> c1
a2 -> c2
a3 -> c1

b1 -> c1
b2 -> c2
```

For A and B I use `JpaRepositories` for persistence.

Then I try to save the instances I created programmatically:

```
@Transactional
public void save(A a1, A a2, A a3, B b1, B b2) {
  aRepo.save(a1);
  aRepo.save(a2);
  aRepo.save(a3);

  bRepo.save(b1);
  bRepo.save(b2);
}
```

I get an exception ("detached entity passed to persist: C") in the third line, because the instance c1 got saved already in the first line.

How can I avoid that? I thought that marking my save method in my service with `@Transactional` would be sufficient already, but obviously it's not.

Of course I could just write

```
aRepo.save(Arrays.asList(a1, a2, a3));
bRepo.save(Arrays.asList(b1, b2));
```

but that only shifts my problem as the exception then occurs in the second line when the b1 that references the already saved c1 should get saved.

How can I save the data structures I created in one method without getting that exception?

Here's the rest of the code:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    private C c;

    public A(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Class B looks exactly the same, class C only contains the ID parameter.

The instances are created within a test case:

```
public class DBTest extends AbstractH2TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testDataStorage() {

        final AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DBTest.class);

        try {
            final PersistService persistService = context.getBean(PersistService.class);

            C c1 = new C();
            C c2 = new C();

            A a1 = new A(c1);
            A a2 = new A(c2);
            A a3 = new A(c1);

            B b1 = new B(c1);
            B b2 = new B(c2);

            persistService.save(b1, b2, a1, a2, a3);

        } finally {
            context.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The superclass for the test I found somewhere on the web and modified it a bit:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = A.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class AbstractH2TestCase {

    public AbstractH2TestCase() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
            JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {

        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);

        final String thisPackageAndSubpackages = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
        lef.setPackagesToScan(thisPackageAndSubpackages);

        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);

        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

}
```

If you want a running version of the code - I checked it in here:

https://github.com/BernhardBln/stackexchange

It's a maven project.

Comment: Could you show the code that initializes the instances of a1-3 and c1, c2?

Comment: I added it, plus a link to github where I put a running example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

on you DBTest-Class

```
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class DBTest extends AbstractH2TestCase {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `@Transactional` annotation is useless because you're not using a container (like J2EE or Spring) to actually figure out that the method must be run in one transaction, so each call to `save()` is a transaction and that's why you're getting a detached entity.

Try using Spring as in [this example](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-data-jpa.html) or [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.M1/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.create-instances.spring).

Comment: I thought I was using a container when obtaining my service via `PersistService persistService = context.getBean(...)`?
And in the abstract super class of my test case, the configuration via annotations seems to be the same as in your xml sample?

Comment: When you create AnnotationConfigApplicationContext you should pass the classes of the beans for which you want annotations to be scanned. You only pass DBTest.class. Try passing the class where you define the save() method.

Comment: I annotated the superclass of DBTest with `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = A.class)` which was sufficient as all classes (in this example) live in the same package. 
The actual problem was indeed that transaction management was not activated, as PepperBob pointed out in his answer. After annotating my DBTest with `@EnableTransactionManagement` everything worked as expected.
I updated my example project on github, you can have a look if you like.